# Marklogic web interface update xml documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, marklogic, roxy

What is a good approach to building a web interface for updating xml documents in a marklogic database.
I came across roxy, which is a ruby gem for configuring and deploying marklogic applications, but after playing around with for a while it seemed that it was more helpful for querying and displaying data rather than updating documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roxy is also a framework that allows you to:
- use/extend MarkLogic's REST API
- use Roxy's REST API - with CRUD rewrite rules in place for you to map to your controllers
- The mVCframework itself is also neatly organized and not overly complicated.  We use it quite a bit.

So, if you do CRUD via MarkLogic's REST api or Roxy or any other, none of these actually give you a frontend of their own.

Our usual formula is a 2-tier solution using Roxy within the MarkLogic app server that also serves the front-end code written in AngularJS. Then everything is managed under Roxy nicely.

If you are interested in samplle 3-tier apps with CRUD support, have a look at github and search for samplestack.  It's a set of reference frameworks for MarkLogic.  It's for MarkLogic 8, but it may give you some ideas..

Comment: Thank you for the detailed info. The sample 3-tier application looks like a great start.

Answer (score 0):

The [MarkLogic REST API](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev) is a good place to start. That gives you a lot of control over the documents, including the ability to update them, while working with the language of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

With Marklogic 8 you can use the new Node.js client + e.g. Express (a small web framework). If you like mainstream development, this seems the best way now.